# Mounting cifs drive gives: mount error(22): Invalid argument

Tags: linux, rhel, cifs

I'm trying to run:

```
mount -t cifs //192.168.56.24/cifsnetapp_share /cifs -o credentials=/root/secrets/secrets,gid=5103,_netdev
```

However I keep on getting the following error:

> mount error(22): Invalid argument

Please help me on this

Comment: Any related messages in `dmesg`? Does the command work without `-o`? Could you try a different combination of `-o` parameters?